# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accumulation_tree.accumulation_tree' on AWS lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, cpython

I'm trying to deploy a simple flask app that uses the `tdigest` module on `AWS Lambda`.

It gives below error:

```
[ERROR] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accumulation_tree.accumulation_tree'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 655, in lambda_handler
    return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 249, in lambda_handler
    handler = global_handler or cls()
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 146, in __init__
    self.app_module = importlib.import_module(self.settings.APP_MODULE)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pybrake.flask import init_app
  File "/var/task/pybrake/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .notifier import Notifier
  File "/var/task/pybrake/notifier.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .routes import _Routes
  File "/var/task/pybrake/routes.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .tdigest import as_bytes, TDigestStat
  File "/var/task/pybrake/tdigest.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tdigest
  File "/var/task/tdigest/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tdigest import TDigest
  File "/var/task/tdigest/tdigest.py", line 5, in <module>
    from accumulation_tree import AccumulationTree
  File "/var/task/accumulation_tree/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .accumulation_tree import AccumulationTree
```

Seems like lambda don't use `CPython`. Is there any solution or work around to use `tdigest` in lambda or any alternative package?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to install accumulation_tree module with pip?

```
pip install accumulation-tree
```

Comment: it's already add in `requirement.txt` in `tdigest` module [Click](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/tdigest/blob/master/requirements.txt#L1).